# Find element index containing given string part

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I want to search for "nana" in myArray and it should return index of "banana" element.

```
var myArray =["apple","banana","cherry"];
```

How can i do that?

i have this but perhaps you have more clever way

```
for(var i=0;i < myArray.length; i++){

    if(myArray[i].indexOf("nana") !=-1) { return i; }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you have already

Answer (score 2):

If `ES6` is not a problem, you can use `array.prototype.findIndex` and `string.prototype.includes`:

```js
var myArray =["apple","banana","cherry"];
var search= "nana";
var index = myArray.findIndex(el => el.includes(search));
console.log(index);
```

Comment: thanks but i target to compatible almost all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use `findIndex`

```
var input = "nana";
var output = myArray.findIndex( s => s.indexOf( input ) != -1 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var myArray =["apple","banana","cherry"];
var input = "nana";
var output = myArray.findIndex( s => s.indexOf( input ) != -1 );
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @JonasW. How? I am fine with `indexOf`. Post your own answer with `includes` and tell us how it is better.

Comment: my hack to get the exact word is adding space after the input variable ```var input = "nana ";```. That way, you make sure you are getting only ```nana``` as a separate word.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers support the following code:

### **`for` + `indexOf`**

```js
var myArray =["apple","banana","cherry"],
    word= "nana";

for(var i=0; i <= myArray.length; i++){
    if(myArray[i].indexOf(word)>-1)
    {
       console.log(i)
       break;
    }
}
```

### **`findIndex`**

Also you can user findIndex and the following browsers support it:
[image]

```js
var myArray =["apple","banana","cherry"],
    word= "nana";
console.log(myArray.findIndex( s => s.indexOf( word ) > -1 ))
```

### **jQuery » Check if exists with `grep` + `indexOf`:**

```js
var myArray =["apple","banana","cherry"],
    word= "nana";
    
var item = jQuery.grep(myArray, function( a ,i ) {
  if (a.indexOf(word)>-1)
  {
     console.log(i); 
     return a;
  }
})[0];

console.log("Is Exists: " + item!=undefined);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: same as my current code (i added later after what you have request)

Comment: @Kad, I included 3 way in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more than one element that matches that search criteria in which case you could use `reduce` to capture them all.

```js
var myArray = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'fenana'];

function finder(arr, str) {
  return arr.reduce((p, c, i) => {
    if (c.includes(str)) p.push(i);
    return p;
  }, []);
}

console.log(finder(myArray, 'nana'));
```

Comment: That would have been useful information to include in the question.

Comment: You can find question at third line of my post

Comment: No. The part about the array being unique. You didn't include that information :)